# How does the @ option operator work in AEM HTL templates

Tags: syntax, operators, aem

I spen a bit of time trying to read the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/expression-language.html) on the AEM `@` operator and the [official syntax](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#116-options) specification, but I do not understand the logic behind.

Let's take this example presented in the documentation:

`${myVar @ optOne, optTwo=bar}`

How will this expression be evaluated? What is the effect of the assignment `optTwo=bar`?.

Or this example in the syntax specification:

```
${myVar @ optOne, optTwo=myVar, optThree='string', optFour=[myVar, 'string']}
```

How each assignment in the list (`optTwo=myVar, optThree='string', optFour=[myVar, 'string']`) will affect the final value to which the expression will be evaluated to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my project we are using this **@** operator to pass values to the Java backend logic. I have created a sample use-case to demonstrate the usage of the **@** operator.

I have created a simple info component with a textfield, a numberfield and a checkbox. The corresponding cq:dialog's .content.xml is as below -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Info"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <tab
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Properties"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <columns
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <name
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                class="field-whitespace"
                                fieldDescription="Enter full name of the user"
                                fieldLabel="Full Name"
                                name="./fullName"/>
                            <age
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield"
                                class="field-whitespace"
                                fieldDescription="Enter the age of the user"
                                fieldLabel="Age"
                                name="./age"/>
                            <married
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                class="field-whitespace"
                                fieldDescription="Check if the user is married"
                                name="./married"
                                text="Married?"
                                value="true"/>
                        </items>
                    </columns>
                </items>
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
            </tab>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

The corresponding HTL file is as below -

```html
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design}">
    Info Component
</div>

<sly
    data-sly-use.info="${'org.redquark.aem.learning.core.cq.text.InfoComponent' @
        fullName=properties.fullName,
        age=properties.age,
        married=properties.married
    }" />

<sly data-sly-test="${info}">
    <h1>${info.details}</h1>
</sly>
```

Here, you can see that in the  tag, we are passing values from the JCR in the variables **fullName**, **age** and **married**.

The java code that will read these values is as below -

```java
package org.redquark.aem.learning.core.cq.text;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;

public class InfoComponent extends WCMUsePojo {

    private String details;

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {

        String fullName = get("fullName", String.class);
        Integer age = Integer.parseInt(get("age", String.class));
        Boolean isMarried = Boolean.parseBoolean(get("married", String.class));

        details = fullName + " is " + age + " years old and is " + (isMarried ? "married" : " not married");
    }

    /**
     * @return the details
     */
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
}
```

Or if you are using SlingModels instead of Java Use API then you can access those values in a typical Sling Model way.

```java
package org.redquark.aem.learning.core.models.text;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Default;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.DefaultInjectionStrategy;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Optional;


@Model(adaptables = Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class InfoModel {

    @Inject
    @Optional
    @Default(values = "Test")
    private String fullName;

    @Inject
    @Optional
    @Default(values = "0")
    private String age;

    @Inject
    @Optional
    @Named("married")
    @Default(values = "false")
    private String isMarried;

    // Variable that will be read in the HTL file
    private String details;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {

        details = fullName + " is " + Integer.parseInt(age) + " years old and is "
                + (Boolean.parseBoolean(isMarried) ? "married" : " not married");
    }

    /**
     * @return the details
     */
    public String getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }

}
```

Of course, then you have to call your InfoModel class in the HTL code as

```html
<sly data-sly-use.info="${'org.redquark.aem.learning.core.models.text.InfoModel' @
        fullName=properties.fullName,
        age=properties.age,
        married=properties.married
    }" />
```

You see, here we are reading the same values which were passed in the HTL code. We can then perform any business logic on them.

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: How does this function with Sling Models?

Comment: @Dileepa, I have updated my answer for Sling Model implementation. Cheers!